# EmailSendDefinition + specify tracking folder

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, soap

Is it possible to specify the tracking folder when created an ESD  / EmailSendDefinition via the soap api?

Doesnt look like it is based off the Objects properties. 
http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/emailsenddefinition/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just went through my SOAP objects which are pretty complete, and I can see no way of doing what you're asking through SOAP.  It looks like it's limited to the UI.